# Apply currency filter to the input field in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi when I am using span tags I can apply the money filter like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>
        {{item.cost | currency}}
    </span>
</div>
```

I am wondering how I can apply same currency filter in input tag. i.e

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="text"  ng-model="item.cost | currency" />
</div>
```

When I try to apply currency filter to the input field as above it doesnt work. Please let me know how to apply currency filter to input field. Thanks

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890364/format-input-value-in-angularjs

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Comment: This is the best library I've found. It displays as currency when the input is not focused, transforms to a number when focused, gracefully handles several non-numeric characters, and keeps the underlying `ng-model`-bound property as a `number` type the entire time. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-input-currency

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I created a simple directive that handles formatting input fields. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7Lq0rns/1/) example. To use it add this to your existing code.

```
<div ng-repeate="item in items">
    <input type="text"  ng-model="item.cost" format="currency" />
</div>
```

And add this directive to your code.

```
// allow you to format a text input field.
// <input type="text" ng-model="test" format="number" />
// <input type="text" ng-model="test" format="currency" />
.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });

            elem.bind('blur', function(event) {
                var plainNumber = elem.val().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: But model value is affected and is not a number, is the formatted string

Comment: I changed this line `return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)` to `return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, attrs.format == 'currency' ? '€' : null)` to add the € symbol instead of the default $.

Comment: @NVO i have changed return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue) to return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, attrs.format == 'currency' ? '€' : null) but still it is displaying '$' symbol

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can not format using ng-model. At least not that way. You will need to create your own directive that implements a parser and formatter. [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940865/angularjs-currency-format-in-input-box-with-ng-model-how-to-get-formatters-to).

There is a pretty good directive our there that does that currently: [ngmodel-format](https://github.com/greengerong/ngmodel-format)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example52-production</title>


       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.min.js"></script>



      </head>
      <body ng-app="">
         <script>
    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.amount = 1234.56;
    }
       </script>
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <input type="number" ng-model="amount"> <br>
      default currency symbol ($): <span id="currency-default">{{amount | currency}}</span>             <br>
      custom currency identifier (USD$): <span>{{amount | currency:"USD$"}}</span>
       </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to apply the filter in your input, because in your input you don't need formated currency, take a look at this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency this is the official help for angular currency filter.

If you are using bootstrap, you can use one of these controls http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic
I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive and apply formatting on value and on blur you can set that formatted value to input.

```
<input format-currency amount="amount">


angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.amount = 2;
})
.directive('formatToCurrency', function($filter){
return {
scope: {
  amount  : '='
},
link: function(scope, el, attrs){
  el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));

  el.bind('focus', function(){
    el.val(scope.amount);
  });

  el.bind('input', function(){
    scope.amount = el.val();
    scope.$apply();
  });

  el.bind('blur', function(){
    el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
  });
  }
}
});
```

link http://jsfiddle.net/moL8ztrw/3/

Answer (score 0):

I found [ng-currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-currency) to work very well for currency inputs. It supports locale-based decimals and thousands separators, and allows a variable number of decimal digits.

```
<input type="text" model="yourModel" ng-currency />
```

Answer (score -1):

**Installation - mat currency-format**

```
$ npm i mat-currency-format
```

**Description**
The directive can be used in html input to automatically change the input to locale currency.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmh5gw)

```
<input type="text"
      mvndrMatCurrencyFormat
      [allowNegative]="false"
      [currencyCode]="'USD'"
      [value]="usAmount"
      (blur)="updateUSAmount($event)" />
```

hope this will help,
Cheers !

Answer (score -3):

> I wrote this directive and it helped me to format currency values. I hope it helps someone.

```
.directive('numericOnly', function(){
    return {

        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((.\d{3}){1})?(\,\d{0,2})?)$/;
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

                var transformedInput = inputValue;
                if (regex.test(transformedInput)) {

                    console.log('passed the expression...');
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                    return transformedInput;
                } else {

                    console.log('did not pass the expression...');
                    transformedInput = transformedInput.substr(0, transformedInput.length-1);
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                    return transformedInput;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This just checks if the input is all numbers disallowing another other character. There is no currency anywhere in the code.