# Input to show currency

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

So I have an input that is type number. Once user saves this, it creates a tile, then the user can edit, and with editing, it populates fields with existing values. This tile pulls bound info via Angular so I can simply put the currency filter in there. This means, the number input in my html just shows as number, and not as currency. Is there a way in HTML 5 for this to show at least the decimal places even if an amount is something like "10.00" versus just "10"?

I have tried using step attribute as step="any".

Here is my input code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 naviaInp">
    <label for="claimAmount">How much are you claiming for each date above?</label>
    <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" id="claimAmount" min="0.00" step="any" placeholder="$0.00" data-ng-model="recurInfo.amount" ng-required="true" navia-min="0.01" navia-max="10000" ng-pattern="/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/">
</div>
```

Comment: `step="any"` should be `step="0.01"` To make actual currency, check angular filters

Comment: No, think you misunderstood. The input applied back is a simple input and not an angular binding. So changing my step attribute above to 0.00 does not do the trick.

Comment: I think this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615452/apply-currency-filter-to-the-input-field-in-angularjs