# How to add a '%' char to the view of input with a ng-model attri?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, input

```js
var sliceApp = angular.module('sliceConfig', []);
sliceApp
    .filter('addPercentSymbol', function()
    {
        return function(value){
            return value + '%';
        };
    })
    .directive('valWithPercentile', function(val)
    {
        if(angular.isDefined(val))
            $scope.speed_print_percentage = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        return $scope.percentage + "%";
    })
    .controller('sliceConfigController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
    {

        $scope.speed_print_percentage = 40;
        $scope.speed_print = $scope.speed_print_percentage / 100 * 150;
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sliceConfig" ng-controller="sliceConfigController">
  <label>打印速度</label>
  <input placeholder="40%" type="text" name="speed_print_percentage" ng-model="speed_print_percentage | addPercentSymbol"/>
</div>
```

I have a `$scope.percentage = 40` in my App.js. I want to display a 40% in my input as a default value. I know if I set the `$scope.percentage = '40%'`, it works. I want to know is there a way that just set `$scope.percentage = 40` to avoid server side process.

```
<input type="text" name="config_percentage" ng-model="percentage">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive. You can search older SO questions for this (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615452/apply-currency-filter-to-the-input-field-in-angularjs)).

If reusability is not a concern, simple solution would be to use [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions),

In controller,

```
sliceApp.controller('sliceConfigController', ['$scope', '$http',     function($scope, $http)
{

    $scope.speed_print_percentage = 40;
    $scope.speed_print = $scope.speed_print_percentage / 100 * 150;
    $scope.valWithPercentile = function(val)){
        if(angular.isDefined(val){
            $scope.speed_print_percentage = val.substring(0, val.length - 1)
        }
        return $scope.speed_print_percentage + "%"
    }

}]);
```

In Html,

```
 <input type="text" name="config_percentage" ng-model="valWithPercentile" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

Comment: @KrisRoofe I think you misunderstood my answer, will update it. First of all, just put the function "valWithPercentile" as scope variable in controller ($scope.valvalWithPercentile = function(){... }). Second, ngModelOptions work with angular 1.3 and above(your snippet is using 1.2.x.) Please go through angular documentation on ng-Model-Options (link in the answer) the syntax usage. There is a plunker link too if you want to play around.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Since it is a input box and we want user to enter some value, wouldn't it be better to just write percent in some span after input, 
<input ng-model="<my-scope-val>" /><span>%</span>

Answer (score 3):

You can write a filter to achieve the functionality

```
app.filter('addPercentSymbol', function () {
  return function (item) {
    return item + '%';
  };
});

<input type="text" name="config_percentage" ng-model="percentage | addPercentSymbol">
```

Comment: when i try it, it shows the 40%, but got an error, angular.js:13550 Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ngModel/nonassign?p0=speed_print_percenta…mbol&p1=%3Cinput%20placeholder%3D%2240%25%22%20type%3D%22text%22%20name%3D<input placeholder="40%" type="text" name="speed_print_percentage" ng-model="speed_print_percentage | addPercentSymbol" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">peed_print_percentage%22%20ng-model%3D%speed_print_percentage%20%7C%20addPercentSymbol%22%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%3E

Comment: and  user cannot type in nothing. when the user try to type a char, it also throws an error in the console,   TypeError: s is not a function
    at $$writeModelToScope (angular.js:26821)
    at angular.js:26815
    at g (angular.js:26736)
    at e (angular.js:26719)
    at $$runValidators (angular.js:26663)
    at $$parseAndValidate (angular.js:26802)
    at $commitViewValue (angular.js:26770)
    at angular.js:26913
    at n.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:17329)

Comment: @KrisRoofe the filter will work to show the % sign after the number.

Comment: @gypsyCoder, run the snippet, you will see the error

Comment: @gypsyCoder, I've post the error in the above comment, a nonassign error